# как открыть новую activity из fragments?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, activity

как открыть новую activity из fragments? выдает ошибку при указании AddActivity

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    private Button buttonAdd;//добавление

    //Overriden method onCreateView
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);


        buttonAdd = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);

        buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view == buttonAdd){
           // Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"test",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),AddActivity.class));

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: лог ошибки пожалуйста

Comment: Активити добавлена в манифест?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего ваше `AddActivity` не прописано в манифесте. В манифесте в `application` пропишите следующий код

```xml
<activity
     android:name=".AddActivity"
     android:label="@string/title_activity_add"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
```

И у вас должно все работать.

Comment: ура) заработало! Благодарю!